# Putting reset button in Rshiny interactive plotting

Tags: r, plot, shiny

I want to add a reset button in an interactive plotting shiny app. The app does the following thing: Capture the position of the mouse when mouse clicks, draws a red dot on that position and connect all the previous positions with blue lines. If the reset button is pressed, then all the red dots and blue lines should be removed and a new plotting process should begin. However, in practice when I click the reset button, the last red dot is still on the plotting region. I am not sure what goes wrong. Thank you for your help.

PS:thanks jcheng5 for providing the plot mouse events!

The server.R is as follows:

```
library(shiny)
N = 30 # sample size
x = sort(runif(N, 0, 10)); y = x + rnorm(N)
xval=NULL
yval=NULL

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
get.coords <- reactive({
    data.frame(x=input$coords$x, y=input$coords$y)
})

actiontype <- reactiveValues()
actiontype$lastAction <- 'draw'

observe({
    if (input$reset != 0) 
        actiontype$lastAction <- 'reset'
})
observe({
    if (input$closepolygon != 0) 
        actiontype$lastAction <- 'closepolygon'
})

output$diagPlot = renderPlot({
    plot(x, y, xlim = range(x), ylim = range(y))
    grid()

    if (identical(actiontype$lastAction, 'reset')) {
        xval <<- NULL
        yval <<- NULL
        actiontype$lastAction <- 'draw'

    } else if (identical(actiontype$lastAction, 'draw')){
        temp <- get.coords()
        xval <<- c(xval,temp$x)
        yval <<- c(yval,temp$y)

        points(xval, yval, pch = 19, col = 'red', cex = 1.5)
        for (i in 1:(length(xval)-1))
             lines(c(xval[i],xval[i+1]),c(yval[i],yval[i+1]),type="l",col="blue")
        if(identical(actiontype$lastAction, 'closepolygon'))
             lines(c(xval[1],xval[length(xval)]),c(yval[1],yval[length(yval)]),type="l",col="blue")         
    }
}, width = 700, height = 600)
})
```

And ui.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

headerPanel('iPED: The interactive ChIP-PED analysis platform'),

sidebarPanel(
    helpText("graph"),
    actionButton('closepolygon', 'Close the Polygon'),
    actionButton('reset', 'Reset')
),

mainPanel(
    plotOutput('diagPlot', clickId="coords", height="auto", width="100%")
)
))
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you test if `actiontype$lastAction` is `'reset'` you immediately set `actiontype$lastAction` to `'draw'` and, so, you enter in the `else` part where `temp` is created and, finally, plotted. Even if you set `xval` and `yval` to `NULL`, the `input$coords` still exists from the previous click. So, the solution should lie in "reseting" `input$coords`.

After many and different tries (e.g. setting `input$coords` to `NULL` etc.), I came up with the following (I indicate with comment wherever I changed):

```
#server.R
library(shiny)
N = 30
x = sort(runif(N, 0, 10)); y = x + rnorm(N)
xval=NULL
yval=NULL
checker <- 1 #### CHANGE

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
get.coords <- reactive({
    data.frame(x=input$coords$x, y=input$coords$y)
})

actiontype <- reactiveValues()
actiontype$lastAction <- 'draw'

observe({
    if (input$reset != 0)
        actiontype$lastAction <- 'reset'
})
observe({
    if (input$closepolygon != 0)
        actiontype$lastAction <- 'closepolygon'
})

output$diagPlot = renderPlot({
    plot(x, y, xlim = range(x), ylim = range(y))
    grid()

    if (identical(actiontype$lastAction, 'reset')) {
        xval <<- NULL
        yval <<- NULL
        checker <<- 0 ####CHANGE
        actiontype$lastAction <- 'draw'

    } else if (identical(actiontype$lastAction, 'draw')){
        temp <- get.coords()
        xval <<- c(xval,temp$x)
        yval <<- c(yval,temp$y)

        ########### CHANGE...
        if(identical(checker, 0))
         {
           points(xval, yval, pch = 19, col = rgb(1,0,0,0), cex = 1.5)
           xval <<- NULL
           yval <<- NULL
           checker <<- 1
         }else
         {
          points(xval, yval, pch = 19, col = 'red', cex = 1.5)
         }
        ############# ...CHANGE

        for (i in 1:(length(xval)-1))
             lines(c(xval[i],xval[i+1]),c(yval[i],yval[i+1]),type="l",col="blue")
        if(identical(actiontype$lastAction, 'closepolygon'))
       lines(c(xval[1],xval[length(xval)]),c(yval[1],yval[length(yval)]),
              type="l",col="blue")
    }
}, width = 700, height = 600)
})
```

What I had in mind is to actually plot the last stored `input$coords` but with 100% transparency and, also, remove the previous click's `input$coords`. The role of `checker` is to fluctuate between `1` or `0` and do exactly that.

This might be more easily accomplished, but I can't think of a more clear way right now.

Comment: This really helps. Thanks a lot. I am on my way to further develop the app.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that your last point isn't disappearing is because once a click has been made, it simply persists until it's replaced with data from a newer click.  As far as I know, this functionality cannot be modified.  But the way that this data is handled can.

It turns out that clickID actually sends 3 numerical values, not just 2, back to the Shiny session: x, y, and a unique identifier double. I figured out that the solution actually lies in making good use of that third identifier.  I stored in a reactiveValue object, let's call it "reactive$uniqueIdentifier", that identifier and only updated a second reactiveValue object, let's call it "reactive$clickedCoordinates", with the clickID coordinates when the the new clickID's identifier was different from the previous.  I then used reactive$clickedCoordinates as the coordinates of the point I wanted to plot.  Then, when I wanted to reset the clicked coordinates and unplot EVERYTHING, I simply set the value of reactive$clickedCoordinates to NULL.  This made ALL plotted points disappear!  :-)